# crear un array dando click en un boton php

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

Hola saludos lo que estoy tratando de hacer tengo un input con un boton como se muestra en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
lo que quiero hacer es que al apretar el boton se vaya agregando a un array en backend(php) y se vaya colocando en mi tabla(javascript) este es el codigo que tengo hasta el momento si alguien me pudiera ayudar se los agradeceria

javascript

```
var t = $('#tbl_cobros').DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    language: {
        "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ resultados",
        "sFirst": "Primero",
        "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
        "sInfo": "Mostrando resultados _START_-_END_ de  _TOTAL_",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando resultados del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
        "sSearch": "",

        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst": "Primero",
        "sLast": "Último",
        "sNext": "Siguiente",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
    }
});
    var referenciatxt = document.getElementById('contrato').value;
    var oficina = document.getElementById('id_oficina').value;
    var usuario = document.getElementById('txt_usuario').value;
    
    var numero = 1;
    if(referenciatxt.length == 6 || referenciatxt.length == 8 || referenciatxt.length == 9){
        console.log("entro al boton");
        $.ajax({
            url:"ajax/pago_cobros.php",
            type:"post",
            data:{oficina:oficina,usuario:usuario,contrato:referenciatxt},
            success:function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                let arr = data.split(',');                   
                t.row.add([arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],"<a href='"+arr[0]+ "'>$ "+arr[4]+"</a>" ]).draw(true);
            }                
        });            
    }`   


<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){



require '../config/conexion.php';
   require '../includes/funciones.php';
   

   $contrato = $_POST['contrato'];
   $objeto = new Conexion();
   $conexion = $objeto->Conectar();
   $oficina = $_POST['oficina'];
   $usuario = $_POST['usuario']; 
   
   $detallesContrato = [];
   $conexion_PG  = pg_connect("host='aquacis-pro-cf.cluster-cuoflxxjyxja.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' dbname='cf_quere_pro' user='usr_consulta' password='Rfv25_1sF79kJ$%'");   
   $query2 = "select cnttnum, titular, mesesadeudo, saldoadeudo , direccion FROM sp_SaldoAdeudo_contrato(".$contrato.")";
   $result2 = pg_query($conexion_PG,$query2);
   
   if($result2){
      while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result2, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) { 
          $nombre_titular = $line['titular'];
          $mes_adeudo = $line['mesesadeudo'];
          $saldo = $line['saldoadeudo'];
          $domicilio_titular = $line['direccion'];
          $domicilio_titularpg = str_replace("'", "", $domicilio_titular);
          
        $datos_insert=$contrato.",".$nombre_titular.",".$domicilio_titularpg.",".$mes_adeudo.",".$saldo;
                    
      }
   }   
}
```

lo edite y coloque el codigo del backend y creo que no me explique muy bien lo que quiero es que cuando introduzcas el contrato en el input aparte de buscar me genere un array con los contratos que vaya buscando, eso se puede?

espero me puedan ayudar saludos

Comment: No entiendo, quieres implementar una funcion de busqueda?  Deberias agregar el codigo del backend

Comment: Haber si entendí. Quieres que el usuario escriba un contrato y presione buscar, si existe lo anexa a la tabla. Entonces el usuario repita la misma operación N veces

Comment: Si efectivamente @JeffersonJimenez y que aparte me guarde ese contrato en un arreglo en backend para poderlo meter a una base de datos

Comment: Mira puedes hacerlo de varias formas, yo lo haría con un datalist e ir seleccionando. Está selección la almaceno en un Input Tag y cuando ya tenga todas mis busquedas completas, paso ese array a php para almacenar en la BD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te pongo un ejemplo de como podrias hacerlo, tu buscador seria un datalist. Cada vez que el usuario vaya seleccionando lo que le conviene vas armando un array en javascript, luego accedes a este y vas dibujando en una tabla,list,card (html) lo que prefieras. Finalmente envias todo lo que el usuario haya seleccionado a php y guardas en tu base de datos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
    input {
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 5px;
        height: 35px;
        width: 250px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        outline: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #000;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-3">
        <form id="autoform">
            <label for="producto">elije un producto :</label>
            <input list="productos" id="producto" name="producto" size="50" autocomplete="off" />
            <datalist id="productos"></datalist>
        </form>
        <button id="envioPHP" class="btn btn-primary">Envio a PHP</button>
    </div>



    <script>
    let PRODUCTS = [],
        ALMACENO = [];

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(function(data) {
                PRODUCTS = data.products;
                let option = '';
                for (let i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
                    option += '<option id="' + data.products[i].id + '" value="' + data.products[i].title +
                        '" label="category : ' +
                        data.products[i].category + ' / brand: ' + data.products[i].brand + '" >'
                }
                productos.innerHTML = option;
            });
    });
    producto.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        let option = document.getElementById('productos').childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
            if (option[i].value === e.target.value) {
                let OBTENGO = PRODUCTS.find(res => res['id'] == option[i].id);
                ALMACENO.push( OBTENGO );
                setTimeout(() => {
                    producto.value = '';
                }, 700);
                console.log('Puedes acceder al array OBTENGO para ir dibujando en HTML lo que estas recojiendo');
                console.log( OBTENGO );
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    envioPHP.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (ALMACENO.length > 0) {
            console.log('Envias por ajax o fetch el array ALMACENO');
            console.log( ALMACENO );
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Saludos amigo, espero te sea de utilidad

Comment: Hola amigo solo que hay un detalle el datalist no me serviria porque el contrato no lo tengo en algun catalogo apenas lo buscaria y el contrato lo introduzco desde un lector de codigos de barras

Comment: de hecho lo que queri hacer es eso pero con solo el boton de buscar pero cuando agrego contratos me toma siempre el primero que inserte

Comment: @user321627 solo te elabore un código que te sirviera de guía, fíjate que todo lo debes manejar con array. Digiere el código que te publique paso a paso y lograras entender y dar rienda suelta a tu lógica de programación.